# jQuery bind() multiple inputs show new value which was changed

Tags: jquery

I got this code:

```
$("input[name=hoehe],
    input[name=bodenfreiheit], 
    input[name=breite], 
    input[name=anzahl], 
    input[name=laenge], 
    input[name=pfosten_anzahl]").bind('keyup mouseup', function (e) {
        console.log(e);         
});
```

Is there a way to find out the new value which was changed? So if it was `hoehe` oder `bodenfreiheit` or etc. which was changed and to what value?

```
e
```

shows nothing

Comment: FYI, the error for your other question is entirely your mistake. Definitely not the language. Open your eyes, and you'll kick yourself when you find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you could get the element which was changed by using `$(this)`, its name via `$(this).attr("name")` and its value via `$(this).val()`.